# How to extract copyright info with a © symbol from an HTML web page using Python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, character-encoding

I am developing a Python 3.4 application which intends to extract all the texts of a tag containing a copyright symbol in an HTML web page. There are two scenarios:

1. A copyright symbol (in a page source view) is represented as a
   decoded **"& copy ;"**, e.g. on https://www.wired.com/account/sign-in/.
   Texts aimed here are **"& copy ; 2018 Condé Nast. All rights
   reserved."**
2. A copyright symbol (in a page source view) is represented as **"©"**, e.g.
   on https://www.aepohio.com/account/login.aspx. Texts aimed here are
   **"© 1996-2015 American Electric Power. All Rights Reserved."**. The
   search should be based on the symbol. I have tried the below option, but
   it does not do the job.

   ```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   url='https://www.wired.com/account/sign-in/'
   webpage=requests.get(url)
   soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')
   for tag in soup.findAll(text=re.compile(r'© | & copy ;')):   
           copyrightTexts = tag.parent.text
   print(copyrightTexts )
   ```

I would really appreciate if someone could provide a typical code using the above web pages as examples. Using BeautifulSoup or any other approach would be fine with me.

Comment: what is the difference between these two scenarios?

Comment: Difference is the representation of the symbol in the page source view of the two webpages. In case one the symbol is decoded as '& copy ;' but in the second case the symbol is in its original form '©'. But my interest is how to get the tag texts in both cases.